# .htaccess issue when including custom 404 error page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

This is my first time using `.htaccess` and currently my `.htaccess` file is redirecting to my custom 404 page. This is being handled with the following line in my `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

On top of this, I need to rewrite a few urls so that `/addition/` points to `/includes/addition.html` (this is one example). So I add the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /addition/ /includes/addition.html
```

But this then serves me a 500 error when Is hold be getting 404 error. On top of this, when I point to `mysite.com/addition/` the browser isn't fetching `addition.html` from my `includes` folder.

Would someone please explain to me how to have these two rules working without effecting the other, and correct my secondary rewrite rule?

Danke.

Comment: try to put first the ErrorDocument rule, and then all other rules

Comment: @anubhava: Admittedly, it should be in my includes folder. But it is currently in my site's root directory. So I don't believe this will be causing it.

Comment: @anubhava: Yes, it loads the correct file. I have reordered my rules as per @Nicholas Nur's suggestion and now the custom 404 loads correctly if I go to a directory that does not exist. However, if I punch in `http://example.com/addition/` I am getting my custom 404 as well, rather than `/includes/addition.html` being fetched. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way in your site root .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/?$ /includes/$1.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you! This has solves the custom 404 showing up when I type in `http://example.com/addition/`. The only other thing is `addition` is one of a few urls that need rewriting. The urls only include `[a-z]`. How would the `RewriteRule` be written to handle any lowercase alpha characters, then find the corresponding file in the `/includes/` folder? e.g. `subtraction.html` --> `/subtraction/` as well.

Comment: Thank you V much. This works perfect. I've also updated my 404 rule and included my custom error page in my `includes` folder. Thanks for picking that up, too. Marked as correct answer and upvoted.